# Destination property uri not provided migrating uri

Tags: 8, files, uri, migrations

I'm working on a file migration from D6 -> D8, and in my case, all the files are already on S3, and they don't need to move, so all I need to do is migrate the URL to a new fid. Based on direction from mikeryan1 in IRC, in my config file I'm just doing

```
uri: uri
```

However, when I try to migrate, I get a `'Destination property uri not provided'` error. I tracked down the code to EntityFile::getEntity():

```
// By default the entity key (fid) would be used, but we want to make sure
// we're loading the matching URI.
$destination = $row->getDestinationProperty('uri');
if (empty($destination)) {
  throw new MigrateException('Destination property uri not provided');
}
```

where getDestinationProperty() is

```
  public function getDestinationProperty($property) {
    return NestedArray::getValue($this->destination, explode(static::PROPERTY_SEPARATOR, $property));
  }
```

Tracking the code all the way through to NestedArray::getValue(), I find that the problem is my `$ref` array does not contain a `uri` key, so getValue() returns NULL.

```
  public static function &getValue(array &$array, array $parents, &$key_exists = NULL) {
    $ref = &$array;
    foreach ($parents as $parent) {
      if (is_array($ref) && array_key_exists($parent, $ref)) {
        $ref = &$ref[$parent];
      }
      else {
        $key_exists = FALSE;
        $null = NULL;
        return $null;
      }
    }
    $key_exists = TRUE;
    return $ref;
  }
```

Here is my migration config file.

```
id: file_s3
label: Files - S3
migration_group: file
migration_tags:
  - Drupal 6
source:
  plugin: file_s3_source
  constants:
    # source_base_path must be set by the tool configuring this migration. It
    # represents the fully qualified path relative to which URIs in the files
    # table are specified, and must end with a /. See source_full_path
    # configuration in this migration's process pipeline as an example.
    source_base_path: ''
process:
    # If you are using both this migration and d6_user_picture_file in a custom
    # migration and executing migrations incrementally, it is recommended that
    # you remove the fid mapping here to avoid potential ID conflicts.
  fid: fid
  filename: filename
  source_full_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/source_base_path
        - filepath
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  destination_full_path:
    plugin: file_uri
    source:
      - filepath
      - file_directory_path
      - temp_directory_path
      - is_public
  uri: uri
  filemime: filemime
  filesize: filesize
  status: status
  changed: timestamp
  uid: uid
destination:
  plugin: entity:file
```

So what do I need to do to my config file to avoid this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that the source data from D6 doesn't have a uri field (it's filename and filepath), so just using a custom plugin to create the uri in the source row gets around it.